# Calculating the cumulative sum with a specific 'date' merged to single column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, amazon-quicksight

I have a database which contains the amounts and dates per user paid. Now some users make payments on the same day and I want to show the cumulative sum of these payments only once per day in a pivot table, which I am creating using Amazon QuickSight.

I have gone through the following, but they provide the cumulative values once per row and I don't have a way to partition on just the date and not on anything else, with the sum over the payment made.

[Calculating Cumulative Sum in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841206/calculating-cumulative-sum-in-postgresql)

[Calculating cumulative sum with date filtering in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47942694/calculating-cumulative-sum-with-date-filtering-in-postgresql)

[Calculating Cumulative daily sum in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66553329/calculating-cumulative-daily-sum-in-postgresql)

[PostgreSQL, renumber and cumulative sum at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21041814/postgresql-renumber-and-cumulative-sum-at-once)

[How to conditional sum two columns in PostgreSQL 9.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41661190/how-to-conditional-sum-two-columns-in-postgresql-9-3/41661446)

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT
    s.id,
    s.first_name,
    s.last_name,
    s.birth_date,
    s.card,
    p.datetime,
    p.amount,
    Sum(p.amount)OVER(partition BY p.datetime ORDER BY p.datetime ) AS "Daily Amount"

FROM payments AS p

LEFT JOIN users AS s
ON p.s_h_uuid = s.h_uuid

ORDER BY p.datetime DESC
```

Where I am doing a Sum() Over() at this row:

```
Sum(pa.amount)OVER(partition BY p.datetime ORDER BY p.datetime ) AS "Daily Amount"
```

My Table has data as:

Users:

```
| id | first_name | last_name | birth_date | card |
| 2  | first_nam2 | last_nam2 | 1990-02-01 | M    |
| 3  | first_nam3 | last_nam3 | 1987-07-23 | M    |
| 1  | first_nam1 | last_nam1 | 1954-11-15 | A    |
| 4  | first_nam4 | last_nam4 | 1968-05-07 | V    |
```

Payments:

```
| p_uuid | datetime   | amount |
| 2      | 2021-05-01 | 100.00 |
| 3      | 2021-05-01 | 100.00 |
| 2      | 2021-05-02 | 100.00 |
| 1      | 2021-05-03 | 100.00 |
| 3      | 2021-05-03 | 100.00 |
| 4      | 2021-05-03 | 100.00 |
| 2      | 2021-05-05 | 100.00 |
| 1      | 2021-05-05 | 100.00 |
| 4      | 2021-05-06 | 100.00 |
```

The output I want is that the "Daily Amount" is shown only once for a specific date, if there are multiple rows with the same date, then for the other rows, it should be blank or display something like "NA":

```
| p.datetime | id | first_name | last_name | birth_date | card | pa.amount | "Daily Amount" |
| 2021-05-01 | 2  | first_nam2 | last_nam2 | 1990-02-01 | M    | 100.00    | 200.00         |
| 2021-05-01 | 3  | first_nam3 | last_nam3 | 1987-07-23 | M    | 100.00    |                |
| 2021-05-02 | 2  | first_nam2 | last_nam2 | 1990-02-01 | M    | 100.00    | 100.00         |
| 2021-05-03 | 1  | first_nam1 | last_nam1 | 1954-11-15 | A    | 100.00    | 300.00         |   
| 2021-05-03 | 3  | first_nam3 | last_nam3 | 1987-07-23 | M    | 100.00    |                |
| 2021-05-03 | 4  | first_nam4 | last_nam4 | 1968-05-07 | V    | 100.00    |                |
| 2021-05-05 | 2  | first_nam2 | last_nam2 | 1990-02-01 | M    | 100.00    | 200.00         |
| 2021-05-05 | 1  | first_nam1 | last_nam1 | 1954-11-15 | A    | 100.00    |                |
| 2021-05-06 | 4  | first_nam4 | last_nam4 | 1968-05-07 | V    | 100.00    | 100.00         |
```

Is there some way that it is possible to get this output from SQL (PostgreSQL specific query)?

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! [mcve]

Comment: I have provided the different ways in which the output can come for a given date, hence the 9 rows in the output. I had put in less rows, but the context goes away then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `sum() over()` computes the wrong amount, try

```
 Sum(p.amount) OVER(partition BY s.id, p.datetime) AS "Daily Amount",
```

**EDIT**
If you want to format output (cumulative amount only once per date), use `row_number()` to detect first row in a group. Make sure `over()` clause is in sync with  `ORDER BY` of the query.

```
SELECT 
        id,
        first_name,
        last_name,
        birth_date,
        card,
        datetime,
        amount,
        case when rn=1 then "Daily Amount" end "Daily Amount" 
FROM (
    SELECT
        s.id,
        s.first_name,
        s.last_name,
        s.birth_date,
        s.card,
        p.datetime,
        p.amount,
        Sum(p.amount) OVER(partition BY s.id, p.datetime) AS "Daily Amount",
        row_number() OVER(partition BY s.id, p.datetime ORDER BY p.amount) AS rn
    FROM payments AS p
    LEFT JOIN users AS s ON p.s_h_uuid = s.h_uuid
) t
ORDER BY datetime DESC, id, amount
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but it still displays the amount once for each row. I want to avoid it to be displayed multiple times for the same "Date". So the desired output is to have it displayed as a cumulative amount only once per date. If the date is present in another column, I want the "Daily Amount" to be blank or some other value like "NA"

Comment: Then first you need a more specific `ORDER BY`  in the query to define the order  of rows in the output.  For example `ORDER BY s.id, p.datetime, p.amount` . And use it to compute row_number () and show only first one amount. What is the desired  order  of rows in the output?

Comment: Okay, will try with a tuple in the ORDER BY clause. The order I want is by the Date field. I was looking at the IF and WHERE clauses, but am unable to formulate the required SQL using those, as the query is a row by row one and for what I want, it might require the whole query to be generated and then a sub-query, which takes the required columns and sorts it in that manner?

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I think just a small change there, as we are looking at the date, would need to convert the datetime to just a date(), else if the time is different, it will start as a new 'rn' again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value only once per date, then use `row_number()`:

```
select (case when 1 = row_number() over (partition by p.date order by p.p_uuid)
             then sum(p.amount) over (partition by p.date)
        end) as day_payments
```